# Getting java.lang.NoSuchFieldError with Amazon Maps V2 API

Tags: android, maps

I posted this in the Amazon developer forum, but thought I would try here too to see if anyone had any ideas.  At least maybe the `supported_abis` issue could be explained a little?  Does the newer maps v2 API no longer have this field included?  The maps debug and release registration has been completed using the current debug and release keystores I have. As shown in the logcat, the maps v2 is loading (until the error of course).

```
compileSdkVersion 28
minSdkVersion 19
targetSdkVersion 28
multiDexEnabled true
buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
```

I am trying to migrate an existing Android app to Fire OS, and cannot get the maps v2 to load.

Using this:

```
<fragment
   android:id="@+id/mission_map"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   class="com.amazon.geo.mapsv2.MapFragment" />
   setContentView(R.layout.mission_map_layout);
```

I continue getting this error in the logs:

Caused by: `java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: android.os.Build.SUPPORTED_ABIS`

> E/AndroidRuntime(10981): at com.amazon.geo.mapsv2.pvt.RemoteContextUtils.loadModule(RemoteContextUtils.java:152)
>
> E/AndroidRuntime(10981): at com.amazon.geo.mapsv2.util.AmazonMapsRuntimeUtil.loadEngineContext(AmazonMapsRuntimeUtil.java:215)
>
> E/AndroidRuntime(10981): at com.amazon.geo.mapsv2.util.AmazonMapsRuntimeUtil.access$100(AmazonMapsRuntimeUtil.java:50)
>
> E/AndroidRuntime(10981): at com.amazon.geo.mapsv2.util.AmazonMapsRuntimeUtil$DefaultEngineLoader.createInstance(AmazonMapsRuntimeUtil.java:613)
>
> E/AndroidRuntime(10981): at com.amazon.geo.mapsv2.util.AmazonMapsRuntimeUtil$DefaultEngineLoader.createInstance(AmazonMapsRuntimeUtil.java:608)
>
> E/AndroidRuntime(10981): at com.amazon.geo.mapsv2.pvt.LazyInitializer.get(LazyInitializer.java:41)
>
> E/AndroidRuntime(10981): at com.amazon.geo.mapsv2.util.AmazonMapsRuntimeUtil.getRemoteContext(AmazonMapsRuntimeUtil.java:325)
>
> E/AndroidRuntime(10981): at com.amazon.geo.mapsv2.MapsInitializer.initialize(MapsInitializer.java:54)
>
> E/AndroidRuntime(10981): at com.amazon.geo.mapsv2.MapFragment$InitializerTask.doInBackground(MapFragment.java:302)
>
> E/AndroidRuntime(10981): at com.amazon.geo.mapsv2.MapFragment$InitializerTask.doInBackground(MapFragment.java:299)
>
> E/AndroidRuntime(10981): at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)

I am trying to run it on a Fire tablet with Fire OS 4.5.5.3. Is this just too old to run it? The app was built with the newest Android SDKs (28) and gradle files, and would be difficult to roll back to an old set.

Other activities and fragments load just fine throughout the app, except for maps v2.

I added it using a local Maven repository.

This is true:

```
return AmazonMapsRuntimeUtil.<em>isAmazonMapsRuntimeAvailable</em>(context) == com.amazon.geo.mapsv2.util.ConnectionResult.SUCCESS;
```

I don't find much on `supported_abis`, at least how it applies to Amazon maps, other than it is a CPU spec. Is this tablet just too old to load? It is all I have to test with. Why does it load other activities and just can't load this amazon maps v2 fragment? Not trying to load location services or anything. The fragment is wrapped in a simple relative layout.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is the device?

Comment: Kindle HDX 8.9.  I think it is a 2013 model.  It is the only thing I have to test with, since there are no true emulators that I can find.

Comment: What is the OS version listed in Settings?

Comment: 4.5.5.3.  So Android 4.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `SUPPORTED_ABIS` field is part of the Android [Build](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build) class. It was introduced in API 21.

Your problem is that your Kindle isn't running API 21. The latest version of Fire OS for the Kindle Fire HDX 2013 is [4.5.5.3](https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html/ref=hp_left_v4_sib?ie=UTF8&nodeId=201357220), which is [based on API 19/KitKat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fire_OS#List_of_Fire_OS_versions).

Sorry, but if you want to test this on Fire OS, you'll need to get a Kindle device that runs at least Fire OS 5, and your app won't work on anything below that. Amazon has [instructions for setting up a Kindle emulator](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/fire-tablets/ft-testing-without-an-amazon-device.html) (sort of), but it's really just the hardware profile of a Kindle with normal Android. It should be enough to see how the app will work on Fire OS, though.

Comment: OK Thanks.  I was afraid it would be something like that.  So if I wanted to run on 19, I'd have to find an older version of Amazon maps v2 API?  Or are all the older Kindle's no longer able to be supported?

Comment: Yes, I was able to run it in an emulator similar to the device, but it did nothing for maps testing of course.

Comment: I don't think you can run it on older devices.

Comment: Really wish Amazon would update their docs.  I kept believing this:  The Maps v2 API is supported on the following devices running FireOS 4.5 or later:

Fire Phone
Fire Tablets (3rd Generation and later)
Earlier tablets do not support the Maps API v2.